# Rotating buffer type file logging utility

Tags: linux, command-line, text-processing

I'am trying to debug a server that throws a lot of logs on stdout/stderr. I need to redirect only last N lines to a file. Something like a rotating buffer feature there in `tcpdump`'s `-C` & `-W` flags. It would be nice if I could view the log while the server is still running and throwing the logs (I could `cp` it in another file to view it). Is there a utility that does this? From my little understanding of `logrotate` tool, it should be run repeatedly. I don't think it fits my need. What I would like is:

```
serverd -d | $TOOL -n 100 srv.log
```

...where at any time `srv.log` contains last 100 lines outputted from `serverd`.

Comment: Related question: [Keep log file size fixed without logrotate](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/439)

Comment: Why exactly do you want this?

Comment: @user606723: As I had mentioned, I am trying to debug a server and it outputs a lot of messages. Redirecting to a file makes it very large. At any time (typically when an issue occurs), I want to see last X number of lines only. Sometimes the server is on embedded device that doesn't have file system space.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch only the last N lines of any file or input stream using `tail`.

```
command | tail -n 100 > file
```

However it sounds like you want a rotating stream of the last 100 lines always in a log file. This is not easily doable. You can regularly truncate the log file by deleting lines or you can use a system like logrotate to cull old data, but there is not an easy way to keep a 100 line FIFO type log file.

Comment: don't forget about `command | trail -fn 100` (perhaps not a solution, but it could be useful) -f is for follow. This command will print out 100 lines and then wait and block on the file writes and output anything new that gets written.

Comment: @user606723, I believe that you meant to write `tail` rather than `trail`?

Comment: oh, yeah, oops.

Comment: @user606723: As far as I know, on a command like you show the `-f` flag is meaningless. Tail will run until the pipeline is closed then exit with or without the flag. In the case of reading a file I think that would accomplish almost the opposite of what the OP is after ... it would read a minimum of 100 lines and then wait for more. He wants to always truncate at 100 lines. The point here is that there is NOT a good answer to this question, I just threw a reminder in about tail so he could use it to skim off of other log files if he really did just want the last 100 lines of something.

Comment: as I said, "perhaps not a solution, but could be useful." When I said "solution", I meant "answer". It's hard to say what his actual goal is here... I was just trying to make him aware of something else that could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain the original poster has found a solution by now. Here's another one for others that may read this thread...

Curtail limits the size of a program's output and preserves the last 200MB of output with the following command:

```
$ run_program | curtail -s 200M myprogram.log
```

#### References

- https://github.com/Comcast/Infinite-File-Curtailer

**NOTE:** I'm the maintainer of the software linked in this answer....

Answer (score 0):

Apache has a program called `rotatelogs`,

Whatever size you like log to grow to, choose half  the size and set no of log files to 2 eg

```
<yourlogGenerator>|rotatelogs -n 2 logfile 5M
```

Will create two 5M logfiles and flip between them.

Here's the [full description of rotatelogs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/rotatelogs.html).

You could add `-L linkname` then you could `tail -f linkname`