# How to rotate tcpdump files?

Tags: logs, tcpdump

I want to take a continuous dump file of particular size and after the dump reached it predefined size the new data should overwrite the file.

Help

Comment: So you want to dump to a file until it gets to say 20MB, and then, start dropping the oldest line from the file each time a new line is written?

Comment: yes @slm that's right

Answer (score 3):

I think your options, without the `-G` switch of `tcpdump` are limited to the method discussed in this U&L Q&A titled: [Keep log file size fixed without logrotate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439/keep-log-file-size-fixed-without-logrotate).

The issue you're going to run into is, that with the alternative methods, a `kill -HUP ...` will need to be sent to `tcpdump` to signal it that the file's been moved/removed,

I'm not sure `tcpdump` is up to doing this, so I think your best option is to get a version of `tcpdump` on the box with this feature, IMO